# Magento 2 Uncaught Type Error

Tags: magento2

I'm getting this error from an extension I installed but I don't know how to fix it.

Error message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 14 passed to Magestore\Giftvoucher\Model\Giftvoucher::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource, instance of Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data given, called in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 93 and defined in /var/www/html/app/code/Magestore/Giftvoucher/Model/Giftvoucher.php:105 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(93): Magestore\Giftvoucher\Model\Giftvoucher->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\Model\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\Registry), Object(Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory), Object(Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\Timezone), Object(Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\CombineFactory), Object(Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\CombineFactory), Object(Magestore\Giftvoucher\Helper\Data), Object(Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager), Object(Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager), O in /var/www/html/app/code/Magestore/Giftvoucher/Model/Giftvoucher.php on line 105
```

Full Method where error is from:

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate,
        \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\CombineFactory $conditionsInstance,
        \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\CombineFactory $actionsInstance,
        \Magestore\Giftvoucher\Helper\Data $helperData,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        \Magento\Email\Model\Template $emailTemplate,
        \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data $pricingHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_conditionsInstance = $conditionsInstance;
        $this->_actionsInstance    = $actionsInstance;
        $this->_helperData         = $helperData;
        $this->_objectManager      = $objectManager;
        $this->_storeManager       = $storeManager;
        $this->_scopeConfig        = $scopeConfig;
        $this->_transportBuilder   = $transportBuilder;
        $this->_urlBuilder         = $urlBuilder;
        $this->_emailTemplate      = $emailTemplate;
        $this->_pricingHelper      = $pricingHelper;
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $registry,
            $formFactory,
            $localeDate,
            $resource,
            $resourceCollection,
            $data
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error usually means your generated sources are out of date. It doesn't seem to recognize that the `$pricingHelper` argument is there, which suggests it hasn't always been (extension upgrade?). Give this a try from SSH:

1. Change directories to your web root (the base Magento folder)
2. Run these commands:

   ```
   php bin/magento cache:clean
   rm -r var/di var/generation
   php bin/magento setup:di:compile
   ```

The first one flushes Magento's cache, to make sure nothing is stuck/out of date there. The second one clears out all existing generated source files. And finally, the third generates fresh copies. When that's done, give it another try.